# Getting List of records with No related records MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wish to know which team in "TX" have not played a game. (In other words Im looking for a selection of records where there is no related record in the many table.)

Here is the SQL:

(Or if You prefer the sql fiddle is here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14106  )

```
CREATE  TABLE `Team` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `State` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

CREATE  TABLE `Games` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Team_ID` INT NULL ,
  `Game_Day` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

    INSERT INTO `Team` (`Name`, `State`) VALUES ('Rams', 'TX');
    INSERT INTO `Team` (`Name`, `State`) VALUES ('Rockets', 'OK');
    INSERT INTO `Team` (`Name`, `State`) VALUES ('Bombers', 'TX');
    INSERT INTO `Team` (`Name`, `State`) VALUES ('Yellow Jackets', 'NV');
    INSERT INTO `Team` (`Name`, `State`) VALUES ('Wildcats', 'CT');
    INSERT INTO `Team` (`Name`, `State`) VALUES ('Miners', 'CO');
    INSERT INTO `Team` (`Name`, `State`) VALUES ('Bolts', 'TX');

    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('2', '2013-03-16');
    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('2', '2013-01-01');
    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('3', '2013-04-16');
    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('5', '2013-02-02');
    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('4', '2013-02-12');
    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('6', '2013-01-09');
    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('6', '2013-01-01');
    INSERT INTO `Games` (`Team_ID`, `Game_Day`) VALUES ('3', '2013-05-01');
```

I should get the result:

```
ID     Name    
1      Rams
7      Bolts
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT `ID`, `Name` FROM `TEAM` 
  WHERE `ID` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(`Team_ID`) from `Games`) 
  AND `State` = 'TX';
```

SqlFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14106/21).

Answer (score 6):

Use an outer join, selecting only those rows that *don't* match

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TEAM t
LEFT JOIN GAMES g ON g.team_id = t.id
WHERE t.state = 'TX'
AND g.team_id is null -- return only rows that *don't* join
```

This this running in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14106/20)

Note that using a join will out-perform a sub-query approach, especially when data sets become large.

Comment: This is a better answer from a performance perspective. MySQL doesn't scale well with sub-queries (which both of the other answers right now use). A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will perform better in the long run.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan Absolutely. Subqueries are to be avoided wherever possible, and can often be converted to a join with the right sql kung fu

Comment: I agree, my answer is not a very efficient one. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: But that subquery is not correlated. If there are conditions set on joined table it might be slower.

Answer (score 4):

You can also left-join to the `Games` table and filter for where there isn't a corresponding `Games` row. This is usually faster than `NOT IN` when the tables have a lot of rows:

```
SELECT Team.ID, Team.Name
FROM Team
LEFT JOIN Games ON Team.ID = Games.Team_ID
WHERE Team.State = 'TX' AND Games.ID IS NULL;
```

If there isn't a `Games` row to go with the `Teams` row, the `Games.ID` column will be null in the result, so if you filter on `Games.ID IS NULL` you'll get all the rows where a team has no games.

There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc634/1).

Comment: Your answer got the tick and more upvotes, is the same as my answer but was posted 3 minutes after mine. You must share how you were able to do that!

Comment: @Bohemian - sorry, I didn't even see your answer. I've known this from years of Oracle work.

Comment: Oh I never though it was plagiarism - it happens often to me too; we're all busy typing answers at the same time and someone hits "post" first. It was more just plain old sour grapes :)

Comment: No worries @Bohemian. I've just upvoted your answer; it's only right.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help.

```
select t.ID,t.NAME
FROM Team t
WHERE t.state = 'TX'
AND t.id NOT IN (SELECT g.TEAM_ID FROM Games g)
```